# Is it possible to have split-panes in monaco editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

Is it possible to get split panes in Monaco editor? Similar to what's done in VSCode or what is being used in the Diff Editor provided by Monaco itself.

Answer (score 8):

You have to share model among editors like

```
const ed1 = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container1"), {
    value: "function hello() {\n\talert('Hello world!');\n}",
    language: "javascript"
})
const model = ed1.getModel()

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container2"), {
    model,
})
```

---

```
<div id="container1" style="height:50%;"></div>
<div id="container2" style="height:50%;"></div>
```

You can test that code in playground https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html