# Monaco editor split column with @monaco-editor/react npm package in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, monaco-editor

I am trying to split my monaco editor into 2 separate columns as one of them will be used for config changes using JSON format for E Charts and other column for showing the code samples for new users to understand the syntaxes. Is there a specific attribute in this package to split into different columns? I also went through this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779773/is-it-possible-to-have-split-panes-in-monaco-editor) but couldn't find a way to do it with the react/typescript. I am declaring the editor like below,

```
      <Editor
          height="100%"
          width="100%"
          theme="vs-dark"
          value={formatCode(editorValue)}
          onMount={handleEditorDidMount}
          defaultLanguage={language}
          options={editorConfig}
        />
```

I also tried to use 2 `<Editor/>` but it only showed one `<Editor/>` . Is there any specific way i need to do follow?

PS: I am using this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@monaco-editor/react